# SQL Error 1452 and auto increment problem

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

Basically my problem is described on the screen below. I've got two tables: payments, tickets. There's a relationship between them. They both have id int auto_increment. When I try to INSERT INTO tickets and the value of the id is set to DEFAULT, everything is fine. But when I try to do the same with payments table, I've got 1452 error. I've gotta write the id by myself, because the DEFAULT doesn't work (though it's auto increment).

Why is that? How to solve this problem? I wish I didn't have to write the id in each query so it could auto increment by itself.

[image: Screen]

Comment: Show us the table definitions and the `INSERT` statement that goes wrong. As formatted text (not images.)

Comment: 1452 is a foreign key constraint fail. Is your PK a FK? If so, why using 2 separate tables?

Comment: Isn't a payment related to a ticket? If so, there should be a foreign key to a specific ticket ID, not (only) an autoincrement. And as mentioned, if there can only be one payment per ticket, it seems unnecessary to have a 2nd table at all.

Comment: @Cid
I just wanted to learn creation of 1-1 relation. Now I know it could be a one table.
So yeah, my PK is my FK. And that's the reason why this error occurs, right?

Comment: @jarlh
I guess that friend below has found the answer. But what do you mean by table definition? Do you mean the query that I've used to create that table? How to find that?

Comment: Table definition means "describe table", more or less. Including foreign keys, default values etc.

Comment: use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) instead of `DEFAULT`

Comment: *"I just wanted to learn creation of 1-1 relation"* This makes totally sense.